# How to manually list set of urls for search engines to index

Tags: seo, ajax

So I have created a video website which has thousands of videos and thousands of videos get added to it on a daily basis. Here is my problem :-

I have created a website which basically loads the skeleton in html and puts all the content through javascript and Ajax. The problem is search engines aren't going anywhere except for the home page.

Is there a way say in robots.txt where i give a link to a single html which has links to all these videos ?

I agree my site is not accessible for a non-javascript user but stats show that this ratio is very low ( > 0.2 % ).

Is there a way I can still keep the complete AJAX website and still get each individual videos listed on google ?

Answer (score 1):

You should add sitemap.xml to your site which gets updated with each new video added.
Refer google's documentation for sitemaps.
[About Sitemap](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=156184)

Comment: +1 You're presumably using some form of CMS to handle all this content. You need to work out a way for it to produce a sitemap file for search engines.

Comment: Ah, that should work. Thanks. Also does the sitemap.xml size have a problem ? We are expected to have 3-4 million videos by end of next year.

Comment: If it is that large amount of videos, you need not add all of them to the sitemap. Just add the recent few thousand videos. Once they get indexed there is no need to keep them in sitemap.xml. This is how even the stackoverflow maintain it's sitemap.xml file for fresh questions.

Answer (score 1):

Google suggests [This solution](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html) for indexing ajax sites which use 'hash bang' urls (I don't know if yours does).